# Trouble getting nested value from API (react native)

Tags: api, react-native, axios

I'm trying to make an app that will show the departures from a specific train station to another and although my code works, I have trouble getting the value I want from the API url. (I have tested it with a different API url and it works)

this is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class DeparturesList extends Component {
  state = { departs: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://extranet.trainose.gr/services/passenger_public/mobile_app/ajax.php?c=dromologia&op=vres_dromologia&apo=ΛΑΡΙ&pros=ΘΕΣΣ&date=2018-01-10&rtn_date=undefined-undefined-&travel_type=1&trena%5B%5D=apla&trena%5B%5D=ic&trena%5B%5D=ice&trena%5B%5D=bed&time=23%3A59&time_type=anaxwrhsh&rtn_time=23%3A59&rtn_time_type=anaxwrhsh')
      .then(response => this.setState({ departs: response.data }));
  }

  renderDepartures() {
    return this.state.departs.map(depart => <Text>{depart.data.metabash.segments.treno}</Text>);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderDepartures()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default DeparturesList;
```

any help would be massively appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so gave fetch a try and with a LOT of research and failed attemps I got what I wanted!!!

here's my code

```
   import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/Header';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://extranet.trainose.gr/services/passenger_public/mobile_app/ajax.php?c=dromologia&op=vres_dromologia&apo=%CE%9B%CE%91%CE%A1%CE%99&pros=%CE%98%CE%95%CE%A3%CE%A3&date=2018-01-10&rtn_date=undefined-undefined-&travel_type=1&trena%5B%5D=apla&trena%5B%5D=ic&trena%5B%5D=ice&trena%5B%5D=bed&time=23%3A59&time_type=anaxwrhsh&rtn_time=23%3A59&rtn_time_type=anaxwrhsh')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.data.metabash,
        }, () => {

        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
      <Header />
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.segments[0].treno}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('trainstation', () => FetchExample);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should take a look at the response you get from the server. First of all, `response.data` is not the list of departs, `response.data.metabash` is what you are looking for.

Here is the structure of the response :

```
{
  "status": int,
  "message": String,
  "data": {
    "metabash": [{
      ttt: String,
      segments: Array<Segments>
    }],
  },
}
```

To get the nested values, you can use something like:

```
this.state.departs.map(depart => depart.segments.map(segment => <Text>{
  segment.treno
}</Text>));
```

Comment: thank you Antoine for the reply!

so I have replaced response.data with response.data.metabash but how do I go to deeper values?

How do I see the response from the server?

thank you again so much!

Comment: if I use for example `.({ departs: response.data.message })); `I can see in the console the result, but I have no any deeper access to the rest of the values :(

Comment: @SuperNDesigns To see the response from the server, you can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), witch is a great tool, then prettify the response with this [tool](http://jsonprettyprint.com/). I've updated my answer on how you could get the nested values

Comment: thank you Antoine! I have added a Chrome extensions that automatically transforms the JSON code to a... pretty one :) I did not know about Postman, so I'll give it a shot. 

I still have troubles with my code but thanks so much for responding!

Comment: unfortunately I still haven't found a way around it. I get this:

 "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

any ideas??

Comment: That's an other question in itself. Have you tried looking on google for this error first? Their is multiple explanations for this error

Comment: yes I have, but no luck. but I get this error after updating my code to what you suggested. :/ thx again for the support.

Comment: I've figured out why I was getting that warning... I forgot to include the parenthesis in `{this.renderDepartures()}`.... silly me!

Comment: ok, back to where i was, when I have `response.data.metabash`, I get a " Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". I have tried various combinations of that on how to go deeper into the array, but no luck :(((

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but are you even trying to debug your code ? Why don't you simply `console.log` your object and see how it is structured ?

Comment: yes I am debugging my code and that's what I wanted to see as well.. anyway,  I think I'm gonna try it with fetch instead of axios.. thanks Antoine for the interest and the help!